# How to specify ListTile height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, height, flutter-widget

In this code, I am trying to make a list of buttons or tiles "as buttons do not work well for me " at the very top of the page. Thus, when one is clicked it returns a value in the rest of the page.

The issue is The tile here toke around more than half of the page which makes it looks inconsistent. I want to limit the height of the tile, I have tried putting them in a row and a container and it doesn't work. Any HELP will be appreciated.

the result after running the code is:

this  is the error after runing the code :
[image]

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 // const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
List<String> temp=new List();
List<String> temp1=['Nile University', 'Smart Village', 'Zewail'];
Map<String,String> map1={};
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
  getplaces(temp);
  getuser(map1,'1jKpg81YCO5PoFOa2wWR');

  }


Future<List> getuser(temp,String place) async{
  List<String> userids=[];
  QuerySnapshot usersubs= await  Firestore.instance.collection('tempSubs').getDocuments();
  QuerySnapshot userid= await  Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('place',isEqualTo: place).getDocuments();
  userid.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc,){
  usersubs.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc1){
    if(doc.documentID==doc1.documentID){
      doc1.data['products'].forEach((k,v){
       
       if( DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(v).day==DateTime.now().day){

        int x= DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(v).day;
                print('keey equal $k and v is $x');

        print('dy is $x');
      userids.add(
      doc.documentID);
       }
      });
      
    }
  } ); }  
    );
              print('doc.documentID');
  print (userids);
   setState(() {});
 return userids;
  }


Future<List> getplaces(temp) async{
    QuerySnapshot place= await  Firestore.instance.collection('places').getDocuments();
  place.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc){
    temp.add(
      doc.data['name']
    );
            //  print(doc.data['name']);

  });
  //  print(temp);
 
   setState(() {});
 return temp;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Home Page"),
        ),
          
  body: !temp.isNotEmpty? 
   CircularProgressIndicator():  
   Row(mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

     children:<Widget>[ 
        Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      child:
           ListView.builder(
             scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
             itemExtent: 100.0,
             itemCount:temp.length,
             itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(temp[index]),onTap:
                (){
                  print(temp[index]);
                }
                 );}
     ),),
     Container(child:Text('data'),)
    ],),
       
        );
          
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code carefully, there are some values called `temp` that we can't see and your code has extra paranthesis (probably leftover from the class)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just remove the `Expanded` Widget to avoid fill the space available and use a parent Container with a fixed height, the same as the `itemExtent` value:

```
    Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemExtent: 100.0,
                          itemCount: temp.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                                title: Text(temp[index]),
                                onTap: () {
                                  print(temp[index]);
                                });
                          }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text('data'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: I have tried this but this error appear : The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
I/flutter (13308): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a horizontal
I/flutter (13308): viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (13308): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (13308): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport

Comment: I donot know why this is happening

Comment: I wrote the same as u did and it still showing me the error I will edit on my code and plaese have a look

Comment: ok, but that's is not the same as my code,  you are using   Row ,  it should be Column  , check the code below your CircularProgressIndicator()

Comment: if you put a screenshot about the design you want, I could help you.

Comment: Your solution works but widgets inside listTile are aligned to the top instead of center. Looks like the only way to fix this is by creating custom widget.

Answer (score 68):

Applying `VisualDensity` allows you to expand or contract the height of list tile. VisualDensity is compactness of UI elements. Here is an example:

```
// negative value to contract
ListTile(
  title: Text('Tile title'),
  dense: true,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -3), // to compact
  onTap: () {
    // tap actions
  },
)

// positive value to expand
ListTile(
  title: Text('Tile title'),
  dense: true,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 3), // to expand
  onTap: () {
    // tap actions
  },
)
```

The values ranges from -4 to 4 and default is 0 as of writing this answer.

However, you cannot use this method for specific width or height size.

Answer (score 13):

You should use a Container or Padding instead of ListTile if you need more customization.

You cannot set the height, but you can make it smaller by setting the **dense** property to true:

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(list[index].name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
              dense:true,                  
            );
          },
        );
```

ListTile:

> A single fixed-height row that typically contains some text as well as
>   a leading or trailing icon.
>
> To be accessible, tappable leading and trailing widgets have to be at
>   least 48x48 in size. However, to adhere to the Material spec, trailing
>   and leading widgets in one-line ListTiles should visually be at most
>   32 (dense: true) or 40 (dense: false) in height, which may conflict
>   with the accessibility requirement.
>
> For this reason, a one-line ListTile allows the height of leading and
>   trailing widgets to be constrained by the height of the ListTile. This
>   allows for the creation of tappable leading and trailing widgets that
>   are large enough, but it is up to the developer to ensure that their
>   widgets follow the Material spec.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html

Answer (score 12):

Since there's no height property in ListTile you can limit the size of a tile by placing it inside a SizedBox:

```
          SizedBox(
              height: 32,
              child: ListTile(..))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `minVerticalPadding` in `ListTile`.

```
ListTile(
            minVerticalPadding: 16.w,
            title: Text(
              _list[index]['label'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            trailing: _list[index]['widget'],
          ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: minVerticalPadding defines the **minimum** gap between the tiles; it can only be used to enlarge the gap, not reduce it.